# Is there a way to not show the windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to, say, suppress InitializeComponent?
I am currently trying to make a sort of Choose Your Own Adventure thing, and I am wondering if it is at all possible to prevent the form from opening, as I work with messageboxes instead of thousands of forms.

Comment: Have you tried `this.Visible = false`?

Comment: You can hide teh form, but that is not adviseable. The difference between a "Message Box" and "Normal Form" is it being called wiht "ShowDialog()" instead of show. Can you change the main to call that one?

Comment: However, a bunch of stacking modal dialogs sound like a terrible idea from so many directons. It am not even sure I understood your goal right.

Comment: Instead of message boxes I would have one form with one rich text box and several buttons at the bottom. Whenever user presses a button more text is added to the rich text box, and texts in all the buttons may change. Having all the previous text is nice for narrative driven game. And rich text is also useful for you, with bold, italics, color change, and such.

Comment: If you're doing a Choose Your Own Adventure, why not go full retro and make a Console app using Console.ReadKey()?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you don't want a form at all and are trying to do everything with message boxes. The design of that aside, you don't need a form in order to display a `MessageBox`. All you need is a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {   
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // gut everything else from the Windows Forms Application template
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```